# How do I manage secure files using a public babushka dep?

Tags: ruby, provisioning, babushka

I want to share my babushka deps in much the same way as The Conversation do: https://github.com/conversation/babushka-deps

However, I manage SSL certificates and SSH keys using chef. Right now those files are directly in my chef config, but as I'd like to share my babushka config I can't put them there.

Is there a good way in babushka to deal with secure, outside-of-repo files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I'm working on at the moment. There's no built-in way, but it can be accomplished with a little bit of scripting.

If you're running the deps on a remote system, say from a shell script, then I'd add a command to the script to first rsync the private data into place:

```
rsync -taP private/ user@host:~/private/
ssh user@host 'babushka "server configured"'
```

That's the simplest case, but it quickly gets messy. Instead, I'm doing this sort of thing with babushka itself, in order to describe the whole process in terms of deps.

I have a dep with a couple of small helper methods for installing babushka on a remote machine, and then running arbitrary deps on it. This allows you to write local deps that depend on the results of remote runs, effectively nesting babushka within itself.

It's not quite general enough to be merged into core yet (and it's in need of a refactor), but it works well. Here it is if you'd like to give it a go in the meantime:

https://github.com/conversation/babushka-deps/blob/master/provision.rb#L123-131

Using this method, you can pass arguments to each remote run. That makes it easy to supply private data, e.g. your private key, or an SSL cert for setting up your webserver, etc.

(Note though that argument values are logged to ~/.babushka/logs/dep-name on the local and remote boxes, so 'private' assumes that the relevant user accounts on both are trusted.)